# how do convert string to list object in java using rxjava

Tags: java, android, json, list

I get a string from the server that returns the following:

`{\"row\" : [{\"name\":\"acb\", \"age\":37}, {\"name\":\"lone\", \"age\":38}]}`

and model

```
public class Row{
    private List<Person> personList;
}
```

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

So how do I get the item name and age into a class `Row` and `List<Person>`.

Give me a way to solve it

Comment: You can use GSON to map json into your class

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jackson object mapper to map this json string to your class.

Below is a sample untested code...

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...
...
     
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(yourString).get("row");
    List<Person> output = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode), new TypeReference<List<Person>>);
```

Comment: but i want to parse to gson not jackson you can do that k